# What is this effect called and How Do I create this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

The part where the human is shown. I have the original image in color and want to convert it into the red effect. What is the effect called and what technique is used.

[image]

Comment: Please try to describe the effect in the title or at least the body of the question. Otherwise, it will be useless for anyone else in the future, cause it wont be searchable.

Comment: I do understand that, but if you read the question carefully I am not very much aware of what the effect is called.

Comment: Thats why I said "describe" not "name" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image you have attached was not created using an effect - this is actually a well-executed vector illustration. You may achieve similar look in Photoshop but the outcome will be nowhere near the provided illustration in terms of quality.

1. Create a new layer above your original photo, fill it with the color you wish (red in your case), and set the blending mode of this layer to `Screen`.
2. Select a layer with your photo, choose `Image > Adjustments > Threshold` and drag the threshold slider until you achieve a satisfactory result.

Comment: If we were to do it in Illustrator, how should we proceed. Though the method shown by you is also satisfactory

Comment: This method of colorizing in Photoshop (Step 1) is applicable to any b/w image (just paste your vector illustration below the red layer instead of photo). If you want to do it completely in Illustrator, you may follow the steps suggested by @Yisela (works in Illustrator as well, just substitute *layers* with *objects*) and then just draw a large red rectangle underneath your vector work.

Answer (score 3):

For a more detail result, you would have to redraw the image. You can do it in Photoshop, but it'd be much easier in Illustrator.

Steps in Photoshop:

- Open the original image and duplicate the background layer,
- Hide the original one, and bring the new duplicated one to 30% opacity or so (at this stage you can play with your adjustments to bring more contraste to the image. This will make the next step easier),
- Create a new blank layer on top of you image,
- Using the `Pen Tool`, draw the darker parts of the image.

The process will kind of look like this, excuse my poor execution, but hopefully the idea is clear!:

[image]